# Cloning items jquery, select drop down not updating correctly

Tags: jquery

On my site, I have an option where users can add multiple guests to a booking and select a package they would like to buy them.

When a package is selected the price automatically updates based on the value of a select option.

For some reason - the  first drop down (that is already on the page) works and updates the price.

However when you run the function `newMenuItem()` the select dropdown it gives you does not update the price.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="margin-top-0 margin-bottom-30">Guest Details <small>(Guests you're paying for)</small></h3>

<table id="pricing-list-container">
<tr class="pricing-list-item pattern">
<td>

<div class="fm-input pricing-name">         <label>Package</label>
    <select data-placeholder="Select Item">
    <option>Select a package </option>

    <option value = "100">1</option>
    <option value = "200">2</option>
        <option value = "300">3</option>
</select>
</div>



<div class="fm-close"><a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="#" class="button add-pricing-list-item">Add Guest</a>


<span id = "price">ddd</span>
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(function () {
                    var fields = $('select').change(calculate);


                    function calculate() {
                            var price = 0;
                            fields.each(function () {
                                    price += +$(this).val();
                            })
                            $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));
                    }
                    })


          function newMenuItem() {
        var newElem = $('tr.pricing-list-item.pattern').first().clone();
        newElem.find('input').val('');
        newElem.appendTo('table#pricing-list-container');
    }

    if ($("table#pricing-list-container").is('*')) {
        $('.add-pricing-list-item').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            newMenuItem();
        });

        // remove ingredient
        $(document).on( "click", "#pricing-list-container .delete", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });



    }



});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1pzxk241/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there seems to be some syntax errors in your JSfiddle, you're missing a ending bracket.

The issue you that you're seeing has to do with the way events are bound in the DOM. You'll find this is the case for any dynamically added content.

**The problem:**

When you create a new select control and append it to the DOM the on change listener is not aware of that control. This is because the listener was applied to all controls that existed when the page first loaded, but is not automatically applied to any that come in afterwards.

**The solution:**

To work around this, you need to apply the on change listener to a higher level object, so that when a child element is added, it will be encompassed in the parent element's listener event.

For your code, this would be replacing this section:

```
$(function () {
                var fields = $('select').change(calculate);


                function calculate() {
                        var price = 0;
                        fields.each(function () {
                                price += +$(this).val();
                        })
                        $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));
                }
                })

});
```

With this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  var price = 0;
  $(this).each(function () {
    price += +$(this).val();
  })
  $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));      
})
```

I would also note that the logic you have in that snippet will only get the value of the last changed control and does not sum the value of all the controls. To do that you'll want to get the value of each selected item.

Like so:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  var price = 0;
  $.each($('select option:selected'), function() {
            price += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
  $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));      
})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This explains a lot. Thank you so much for the in depth details. Appreciate it greatly

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your function with this

```
$(function () {
                var fields = $('#pricing-list-container').on(
        {
            change: function ()
          {
                            var price = 0;
                            price += +$(this).val();
            $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));

          }
        },'.pricing-list-item select');
});
```